# spring boot + docker + apache log4j

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to run a spring boot app(basic - just a controller displaying welcome !) on docker.
Image is getting created successfully, but when I run it, it says below error.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your DockerFile?

Comment: I solved this my creating an uber-jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following dependencies into you `pom.xml` then rebuild and check again:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```